# How to add elements in NSArray in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I want to add multiple elements in NSArray with @"title" and value.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    BSDevice *d=[[DeviceManager devices] objectAtIndex:i];
    self.dataArray =@[@{@"title":d.Name}];
}
```

But in this code it only adds one value. When I try with this method it doesn't work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    BSDevice *d=[[DeviceManager devices] objectAtIndex:i];
    [self.dataArray addObject:@[@{@"title":d.buddyName}]];
}
```

I want to have multiple values with string and its value in NSArray like this `@"title":d.Name,@"title":d.Name,@"title":d.Name`

Comment: What's the problem? It's unclear what issue you are having with the code you posted.

Comment: I want to add multiple values in an array using loop. But first the string and then value of that string. Any idea

Comment: Maybe `[DeviceManager devices]` only has one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear and you didn't really explain what problem you are having with the second bit of code, but I think what you want is the following:

```
for (BSDevice *d in [DeviceManager devices]) {
    [self.dataArray addObject:@{ @"title" : d.buddyName }];
}
```

This assumes that `self.dataArray` is an `NSMutableArray` and somewhere before this `for` loop you initialized `self.dataArray` as:

```
self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am beginner with Objective C, but highly appreciated man